# The frama-c impact analysis can't analysis control dependence?

Tags: frama-c

When I use the frama-c analysis my c program. It seems there exits a bug in the impact plug in of the frama-c. This is my program.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int global;
int main()
{
    global = 12;
    int result = 0;
    if(global > 1)
    {
         result += 100;
    }
    else
    {
        result += 200;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I want to find all the stataments impacted by the variable "global".
Obviously, the statement "result += 100;" in the scope of "if condition" which is related to the variable "global", so the statement "result += 100;" should be high light.
However, the running result seems not correct.

Comment: Could you provide the exact command line that leads to the result you deem unsatisfying?

Comment: I think I see where this is going, but anyway, your example would be clearer if it did not have two identical statements `result += 100;`. Or if you did not refer to “the” statement `result += 100;` as though there were only one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming that you have used no special option, and that you have started the impact analysis in Frama-C's GUI, on the statement `global = 12`. If it is not the case, please provide more detailed instructions.

In your program, the `if (global > 1)` instruction gets selected because there is a data dependency to the statement `global = 12`. However, the statement `result += 100` does not get selected by the Impact plugin. This is the intended behavior, because there is *no* control dependency in this case. Notice that the `else` branch of the `if` is dead. Thus, the execution of `result += 100` does not really depend on the evaluation of `if (global > 1)`, as the condition is always true. As the control flow always reaches `result += 100` instruction, no control dependency exists.

If you want to exhibit a control dependency in this example, the simplest way consists in changing your line `global = 12` into

```
global = Frama_C_interval(0,100);
```

and to add the file `$(SHARE)/frama-C/libc/__fc_builtin.c` to the command-line. The two instructions `result += 100` and  `result += 200` will get selected, in each case because of a control dependency.